# Parents-in-law in Japanese

Tags: synonyms, nouns

I have found three different words meaning *parents-in-law*:

- [舅姑]{きゅうこ}
- [義父母]{ぎふぼ}
- [義理]{ぎり}の[親]{おや}

But I'm sure the words are not interchangeable.

How are the words different? What would be the right way to use each of the words?

Answer (score 7):

A [corpus](https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/) is a good tool to answer this type of question yourself.

- 舅姑: 30 Hits (Many instances are from the same author born before 1960's)
- 義父母: 50 Hits (Many are from blog articles and chiebukuro questions)

  - 義母: 758 Hits
  - 義父: 536 Hits
- 義理の親: 7 Hits

  - 義理の母: 30 Hits
  - 義理の父: 33 Hits
- 義親: 20 Hits

IMHO, 舅姑 sounds old, and it may have an unwanted connotation (the kanji 姑 is often used to refer to bad MIL/DIL relationships, aka 嫁姑問題). If you want a safe and neutral word, I recommend 義父母 or 義理の親.